client.chat.completions.create for Ollama
I am trying to do a chat with snowflake by following this page
https://quickstarts.snowflake.com/guide/frosty_llm_chatbot_on_streamlit_snowflake/#5
In this example, OpenAI is used here
if st.session_state.messages[-1]["role"] != "assistant":
    with st.chat_message("assistant"):
        response = ""
        resp_container = st.empty()
        for delta in client.chat.completions.create(
            model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
            messages=[{"role": m["role"], "content": m["content"]} for m in st.session_state.messages],
            stream=True,
        ):
            response += (delta.choices[0].delta.content or "")
            resp_container.markdown(response)

I want find out how can I modify this portion here to use Ollama instead?
Spend a lot of hours trying to do this.
Thanks in advance for any help attempted.
My final attempt is this
        # Generate response
        for delta in ollama.chat(model='llama3', messages=[
          {
            'role': 'user',
            'content': prompt,
          },
        ]):
            response += (delta.response['message']['content'] or "")
            resp_container.markdown(response)


Of course it does not work
